# Java error outofmemory when in xfce but not in windows 7

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I have been writing a program to create a dashboard for work and it works correctly on Windows 7 in eclipse and even as a jar file. When I zip it and send it to the xfce linux (new to using it, not sure if that is the proper name, installed on Chromebit), it is started when I type into the terminal the following command:

```
java -jar projectTimeline.jar
```

But after a few seconds, it throws an error and loops until the terminal is closed

```
    (xenial)gvsprojectstatus@localhost:~/Downloads/projectTimeline/ProjectTimeline$ 
java -jar projectTimeline.jar

REBUILDING

cnzr6890mrtsyznrr1z86duenm
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Smartsheet successful
Workspace Connected
30 Timeline Sheets found
Fetching Sheet 1 of 30
Creating project row from 172023
Fetching Sheet 2 of 30
Creating project row from 172027
Fetching Sheet 3 of 30
Creating project row from 172022
Fetching Sheet 4 of 30
Creating project row from 172040-002
Fetching Sheet 5 of 30
Creating project row from 172041-002
Fetching Sheet 6 of 30
Creating project row from 172042-002
Fetching Sheet 7 of 30
Creating project row from 172052
Fetching Sheet 8 of 30
Creating project row from 172048
Fetching Sheet 9 of 30
Creating project row from 172053
Fetching Sheet 10 of 30
Creating project row from 172056
Fetching Sheet 11 of 30
Creating project row from 162023-002
Fetching Sheet 12 of 30
Creating project row from 172058
Fetching Sheet 13 of 30
Creating project row from 172059
Fetching Sheet 14 of 30
Creating project row from 182001
Fetching Sheet 15 of 30
Creating project row from 132101-003
Fetching Sheet 16 of 30
Creating project row from 182002
Fetching Sheet 17 of 30
Creating project row from 182003
Fetching Sheet 18 of 30
Creating project row from 162020-003
Fetching Sheet 19 of 30
Creating project row from 182005
Fetching Sheet 20 of 30
Creating project row from 182006
Fetching Sheet 21 of 30
Creating project row from 182007
Fetching Sheet 22 of 30
Creating project row from 142091-008
Fetching Sheet 23 of 30
Creating project row from 162003-002
Fetching Sheet 24 of 30
Creating project row from 182013
Fetching Sheet 25 of 30
Creating project row from 172033-002
Fetching Sheet 26 of 30
Creating project row from 172054-002
Fetching Sheet 27 of 30
Creating project row from 182015
Fetching Sheet 28 of 30
Creating project row from 162023-002-001
Fetching Sheet 29 of 30
Creating project row from 172005-004
Fetching Sheet 30 of 30
Creating project row from 182016


Data Retrieved from Smartsheet
Data Received
ERROR #INVALID,DATA TYPE 
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3210)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3181)
    at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:265)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:239)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:231)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:462)
    at appScreen.centreString(appScreen.java:565)
    at appScreen.paintComponent(appScreen.java:643)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:290)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3210)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3181)
    at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:265)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:239)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:231)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:462)
    at appScreen.centreString(appScreen.java:565)
    at appScreen.paintComponent(appScreen.java:643)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:290)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3210)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3181)
    at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:265)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:239)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:231)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:462)
    at appScreen.centreString(appScreen.java:565)
    at appScreen.paintComponent(appScreen.java:643)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:290)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3210)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3181)
    at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:265)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:239)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:231)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:462)
    at appScreen.centreString(appScreen.java:565)
    at appScreen.paintComponent(appScreen.java:643)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:290)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
^C(xenial)gvsprojectstatus@localhost:~/Downloads/projectTimeline/ProjectTimeline$
```

From this, it seems to back up in the centreString method I created. This is below

```
private void centreString(Graphics g,Rectangle r,String s,Font font,Color c) {
    if(s!=null) {
        ArrayList<String> toPrint =new ArrayList<String>();//what will be shown on screen
        String secondLine="";
        String oldTempLine,newTempLine;
        oldTempLine=newTempLine="";

        //get first line out. this was predefined to be alone
        String[] firstLineSplitting=s.split("\n");

        if(firstLineSplitting.length>1) {//if first line is supposed to be alone, insert it and prepare the rest for more processing
            toPrint.add(firstLineSplitting[0]);

            //all other parts of the string, merge into 1 string again
            for(int i=1;i<firstLineSplitting.length;i++) {
                secondLine+=firstLineSplitting[i]+" ";
            }
        }
        else {//not supposed to be alone, put back together
            for(int i=0;i<firstLineSplitting.length;i++) {
                secondLine+=firstLineSplitting[i]+" ";
            }
        }

        //split into words
        String[] theRest=secondLine.trim().split(" ");

        FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics(font);

        for(int i=0;i<theRest.length;i++) {
            String word = theRest[i];
            newTempLine+=" "+word;//add each new word to a test line,
            if(metrics.stringWidth(newTempLine)>r.width) {//and check if it does not fit
                toPrint.add(oldTempLine);//if it does not fit, use the line without that word and start again with that word
                newTempLine="";
                oldTempLine="";
                i--;
            }
            else if(i==theRest.length-1) {//if at the end of the words and do not have a full line, 
                toPrint.add(newTempLine);//use it anyway
            }

            else {//otherwise, the word fits, the older sentence is updated, and this starts again
                oldTempLine=newTempLine.trim();
            }

        }


        int x,y; 
        for(int i=0;i<toPrint.size();i++) {//for each line to be printed,
            x=r.x+ (r.width-metrics.stringWidth(toPrint.get(i)))/2;//vertically centre it 
            if(toPrint.size()>2) {//if there are more than 2 lines to go into this cell
                y=r.y+ r.height/2-metrics.getHeight()/2 + metrics.getAscent()*(i);//raise up the first line 1 line
            }
            else {
                y=r.y+ r.height/2-metrics.getHeight()/2 + metrics.getAscent()*(i+1);//place the first line in the centre
            }

            //draw it on screen
            g.setFont(font);
            g.setColor(c);
            g.drawString(toPrint.get(i), x, y);
        }
        toPrint.clear();
        theRest=null;

    }

}
```

I have tried using -Xms1g, -Xms120m and -XX:MaxPermSize=1g. The first 2 just delay it, while the last one seems to have been removed in Java 8.

If you have an idea on how to fix this, let me know. I have been searching for a day and a half now and they all say make the space bigger with the above commands.

If you need any more material, let me know
Thank you for all of the help

[Image from Visual VM on linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnCKv.png)

Comment: Profile your software and see what's using memory etc.

Comment: also `-Xmx2G` is the parameter to increasing maximum heap size, not `-Xms2G`

Comment: @Kayaman memory in Windows 7 never goes above 211 megabytes, in xfce, it goes to the max I set, which was just now 1 gigabyte.

Comment: @Link64 I tried both of those and both of them just delay the same error

Comment: Who cares what the memory goes to, I told you to find out **why** it goes that high. Profile your application and you can stop guessing.

Comment: @Kayaman How do I profile it in xfce? This is my first time working with linux and it is a fresh copy.

Comment: Just like you'd do on any platform. I'm guessing you've never actually profiled an application. Start with [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/): If you have OpenJDK installed you can run it by typing `visualvm` on the terminal. For further instructions use Google.

Comment: Finally was able to run visual vm. see image at end of main question

Comment: Nice image, although completely useless to me. Unless you want me to tell you "half of the memory used is going to `char[]`, and half is divided between `String` and `StringBuilder` objects".

Comment: I do not know what image you are looking for, this is the only screen it produces. None of them have variable names on them. this one was from the linux one. I ran the same test on windows 7, both have char array large, but do not give what they are from

Comment: I don’t know if this is the cause of your problem, but you are using a great deal of memory by using `+=` with String variables.  That is a highly wasteful way to append to a String, because you aren’t actually changing the String, but rather you are creating a handful of new Strings with each append.  Never use `+=` with a String in a loop;  use a StringBuilder instead.